# Json for Android 2.2 not working

Tags: android, json

I my application which I tested with emulator and phone Andorid 4.1 and Android 2.2.
On Android 4.2 everything works ok also on emulator with API 17.

But on 2.2 I get error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String

I did go debugging and the error occurs at line marked with stars.

Before error I also get notice: Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
public void buildData(String jsonString, String code) {
    mProduct = new HashMap<Integer, Product>();
    try {
        **JSONArray array = (JSONArray) new JSONTokener(jsonString).nextValue();**
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
            JSONObject json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            if(json.has(JSON_PRODUCT)){
                buildProduct(json.getString(JSON_PRODUCT), code);
            }
            else if(json.has(JSON_NAME)){
                buildUser(json.getString(JSON_NAME));
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I use this code for downloading data:

```
public byte[] getUrlBytes(String urlSpec) throws IOException{
    URL url = new URL(urlSpec);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

        if(connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            return null;

        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        out.close();
        return out.toByteArray();

    } finally {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

I should also append example of jsonString that I send.

```
{"PRODUCT":{"0":"1","product_id":"1","1":"sdasd","name":"sdasd","2":"1","person_id":"1","3":"image","image":"image","4":"0","alergen_id":"0","5":"0","contain":"0","6":"-1","aditiv_id":"-1","7":"0","tmpgrade":"0"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "PRODUCT": {
        "0": "1",
        "1": "sdasd",
        "2": "1",
        "3": "image",
        "4": "0",
        "5": "0",
        "6": "-1",
        "7": "0",
        "product_id": "1",
        "name": "sdasd",
        "person_id": "1",
        "image": "image",
        "alergen_id": "0",
        "contain": "0",
        "aditiv_id": "-1",
        "tmpgrade": "0"
    }
}
```

I don't see any array in your json , maybe  your object graph changes sometimes?

Do a check before Casting:

```
Object object = new JSONTokener(jsonString).nextValue();
object = (object instanceof JSONArray) ? (JSONArray)object : (JSONObject)object ;
```

Comment: on Andorid 4.2 is casted to JSONArray and on Android 2.2 is casted to JSONObject. The jsonString is like you wrote it, but, this is only one Array. If we say string that you wrote (above) it is one x, than I have [x,x,x,x,x] = jsonString

Comment: @5er I didnt get it , please clarify.. did you solve your issue?

Comment: No I didnt.. I leave it as it is, for now. I will have to fix this issue. I dont have a solution jet.

Comment: Ok I understand your earlier comment now, is your JSON always an array?

Comment: Yes, and there are two different keys JSON_PRODUCT and JSON_NAME.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to use

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
```

or

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

instead of using

```
Object object = new JSONTokener(jsonString).nextValue()
```