# Json in Android not working as it should

Tags: android, json

I have a problem with Json in android. In 4+ it works like a charm but in 2.2 it fails. I'm really stuck here.

I get error I get error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String

In my server I parse array as:

```
[{"PRODUCT":
    {"product_id":"1",
    "name":"name1"}},
 {"PRODUCT":
    {"product_id":"2",
    "name":"name2"}},
 {"PRODUCT":
    {"product_id":"3",
    "name":"name3"}},
 {"USER":{"user_id":"1"}
}]
```

in android app i use code as:

```
public void buildData(String jsonString, String code) {
    mProduct = new HashMap<Integer, Product>();
    try {

**here fails -> JSONArray array = (JSONArray) new JSONTokener(jsonString).nextValue();

//          Object object = new JSONTokener(jsonString).nextValue();
//          object = (object instanceof JSONArray) ? (JSONArray)object : (JSONObject)object ;
//          JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(jsonString).nextValue();
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
            JSONObject json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            if(json.has(JSON_PRODUCT)){
                buildProduct(json.getString(JSON_PRODUCT), code);
            }
            else if(json.has(JSON_NAME)){
                buildUser(json.getString(JSON_NAME));
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if the array is in the right form? If anyone can help me please.

Comment: "it fails" isn't a very good description of a bug. Is it crashing, and do you have a LogCat for it? Is it parsing incorrectly, and do you have a print out of what parsed? is it a completely different issue all together?

Comment: [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) is useful for checking if your json is in the right form.

Comment: It is in the right form.

Comment: RE: your edit: try to avoid making [duplicate questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319765/json-for-android-2-2-not-working)

Have you looked up what a ClassCastException means yet?

Comment: Google "online json validator" and you will find it. I already checked it, and the json is valid.

Comment: I did found the problem. It is in encoding. It seems that in front of the JSON object is some strange character. I will go deeper to find who is cousing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should change the line to the following:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
```

Then you can loop through it.